# Core data advice

Tags: ios, core-data, relationships

I have created an entity called Subject. Inside the Entity I have placed all the attributes that I only need once for each entry created. Then I have created homework enitity and linked it to the Subject class. My question is am I correct in thinking that I can create multiple homework objects linked to each Subject object I make in my app.

For instance I make a Subject entry with subject='Maths' then in through the Maths entry able to add lots of different homework entries.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship between Homework and Subject is currently a one-to-one relationship (as seen that you have 1 arrow pointing to the word homework and 1 arrow pointing to newRelationship). To add multiple homework objects to a  subject, change the relationship to a one-to-many relationship.

```
Schedule *schedule;
Homework *homework;

for (Homework *homework in schedule.homework) {
    NSLog(@"homework = %@", homework);
}

[schedule addHomeworkObject:homework];
```

Comment: I had a feeling that was something I needed to do. Then do I access the homework entities by fetching the Subject?

Comment: Thanks. I'm just going to ask, how do I write to homework through the Subject?

Comment: Edit answer to illustrate.

Comment: Thank you for your help Kevin it was really useful. I am struggling to understand why I would want to use relationships other than to keep it tidy. For instance, obviously I want my homework tasks to be linked to the subject but why not just put the subject in the homework class. When I want to fill a tableview with homework from a specific subject using relationships means I first have to fetch the subject then fetch the homework. I know that I can fetch the homework by itself but if I cant fetch it by which subject it's attached to it seems a waste of time. Is their persist by parent entity?

Comment: line 3: by subject I mean create an attribute in homework called 'subject' @Kevin

Comment: So that you can easily fetch a all the homework for a single subject. Thinking of a general use case - you fetch all the Subjects into a tableview. When a Subject is selected, you show all the homework. Also, you have a lot of information in one subject, so it would be a waste to copy that information into every Homework assignment.